# Trying to push Django app to Heroku - error around anaconda?

Tags: python, django, heroku, anaconda

I'm trying to push a Django app that uses NLTK and Scikit-learn. I have put all the relevant dependencies in the requirements.txt file, but I keep getting this error. Any suggestions?

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: Collecting alabaster==0.7.10 (from -r /tmp/build_e87edffdf382e76739e44cf354aacd2b/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: Downloading alabaster-0.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote: Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.5 (from -r /tmp/build_e87edffdf382e76739e44cf354aacd2b/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.5 (from -r /tmp/build_e87edffdf382e76739e44cf354aacd2b/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote: No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.5 (from -r /tmp/build_e87edffdf382e76739e44cf354aacd2b/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote: ! Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to XXX.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/secure-mountain-49046.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/XXX.git'
```

Comment: Seems like the version doesn't exist. Try removing the version and you will see something like this: `Downloading anaconda-client-1.2.2.tar.gz (64kB)`

Comment: Removing the version from where? Anaconda isn't in my requirements.txt file